# Setting text of TextView always visible in ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scrollview with some textviews in it.

Some of textviews are wider than the screen, so the text (which is centered) won't appear, like on this drawing :

What I have :
[image]

What I want :
[image]

Is there a way to make the text appear always on the screen ?

PS : my code mix a lot XML and java, for this topic, please consider this dummy XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="800dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="#0000ff"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you are using fixed width. use layout_weight property to avoid overflow. Can you post the layout xml so that i can see if this will fix it for you.

Comment: Yes, but overflow is fully on purpose, I don't want to avoid it.

Comment: okay. So you basically want to scroll to the position where the text it?

Comment: can you post your code here....

Comment: Dan, in the three images under "what I want", you are showing the text in different places depending on where the viewport is.  Using the `HorizontalScrollView`/`LinearLayout`/`TextView` design you posted, the text is only going to lay out in one spot.  In other words, your three images should be showing the text in the exact same place with only the viewport in different places.  Your "what I have" image makes perfect sense with the layout XML you've posted. You should probably add some specifics about your application and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Typically, developers would use a `ViewPager` for this sort of horizontal scrolling view.  I'm wondering if `ViewPager` might be a better choice for your application.

Comment: @krislarson You just proove that you understood perfectly what I have and what I want, which specifics do you want ? Besides, I cannot see how could I use a viewpager for this, could you explain a bit ?